Execute a stored procedure for a list of values using while loop from a query resultset in SQL Server 2008 R2
I am trying to execute a stored procedure for the list of values from a query using a while loop but the while loop is taking forever to complete.
CREATE PROCEDURE ItemsToBeCleared
    @BatchDays INT
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @oldestRecord DATETIME,
            @DataRetentionPeriod INT, 
            @BatchHours INT

    SELECT @oldestRecord = MIN(pt.ptStampDateTime) 
    FROM database1 pt 
    INNER JOIN database2 f ON (f.flcode = pt.ptcommodity) 
    WHERE pt.ptcommodity NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF') 

    SELECT @BatchDays = ISNULL(@BatchDays, 30) -- -- For each Agent Job run, select records for a maximum period of X hours

    SELECT @DataRetentionPeriod = 168

    SELECT   
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pt.assigndatetime) AS RowID, 
        pt.ptStampDateTime,
        pt.ptguid,
        pt.ptversion   
    INTO   
        #temp1
    FROM   
        database1 pt
    INNER JOIN 
        database2 f ON f.flcode = pt.commodity
    WHERE  
        pt.commodity NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
        AND pt.ptStampDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, @BatchDays, @OldestRecord)
        AND pt.ptStampDateTime < DATEADD(HOUR, @DataRetentionPeriod * -1, GETDATE())

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #temp1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No Records Found', 16, 1)
    END
  
    DECLARE @cnt INT,  
            @RowCount VARCHAR(100), 
            @ptGUID VARCHAR(max), 
            @ptVersion INT
  
    --Create temp table to stored the output results from execution of [TACT].[Modifypackagetrans] in a global temp table so that it can be used in sp_send_dbmail 
    IF OBJECT_ID('##results', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE ##results

    CREATE TABLE ##results
    (
       packid     VARCHAR(20),
       ptstamp    VARCHAR(20),
       tankerid   INT,
       assigntime DATETIME,
       ptamount   MONEY,
       route      VARCHAR(10),
       commodity  VARCHAR(20),
    )

    SET @cnt = 0

    SELECT @RowCount = Count(1) FROM #temp1

    WHILE @cnt < @RowCount
    BEGIN
        SELECT @cnt = @cnt + 1

        SELECT TOP 500 
            @ptGUID = ptguid,   
            @ptVersion = ptversion 
        FROM   
            #temp1 
        WHERE  
            rowid = @cnt   
        ORDER BY
            rowid

        INSERT INTO ##results
            EXECUTE [TACT].[StoredProcName]
                -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure   here
                @ptGuid = @ptGUID,
                @ptVersion = @ptVersion,
                @ptAmount = NULL,
                @ptCommodity = NULL,
                @ptTo = NULL,
                @ptRoute = NULL,
                @ptStatus = 'c',
                @UserName = 'ABC\firstname.lastname',
                @showOutput = 1
      END

      -- now send the query results from ##results table to the user
      DECLARE @qry varchar(4000)
      DECLARE @Column1Name VARCHAR(255)

      SELECT @Column1Name = '[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ProcessedDate]'
      SELECT @qry = 'SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS ' + @Column1Name + ',  * FROM   ##results'

      ---- Send the e-mail with the query results in attachment
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
               @recipients = 'first.lastname@abc.com',
               @query = @qry,
               @subject = 'TEST-TACT Clearance List',
               @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
               @query_attachment_filename = 'Test-learanceList.csv',
               @query_result_separator = ',',    -- enforce csv
               @query_result_no_padding = 1,     -- trim
               @query_result_width = 32767       -- stop wordwrap
 
    DROP TABLE #temp1
    DROP TABLE ##results
END

In this procedure I have added a filter the the query (which is inserting into #temp1) to only filter out records that are less that the last 30 days (batchdays) and also add a filter for the @dataretentionperiod, i.e, the query will only run for data till last week (168 hours).
I have then added 'top 500'  to the temp table values inside while loop so that the loop is executed for first 500 records only first. This, however, takes hours to finish. There are around 6000 records produced in #temp1 table.
Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation?
What am I doing wrong?
When the #temp1 table has 3-5 records - it finished in few seconds..

SQL Server 2008 is long out of support.

Any other suggestion would be highly appreciated...

You need to view the execution plan to find out what is taking the time... at a guess you are missing a critical index. If you don't understand the execution plan, then add it here using "Paste The Plan"

you are right @Dale adding indexes to the tables getting purged solved the issue!. Deleted the same indexes in the same stored procedure. Now the stored procedure runs in a few seconds
